# How can I set length limit on Local Storage?

Tags: javascript

I want to limit Local-Storage length on just 5.
So I made some Code. But I don't know how to deal with length limit.

Already tried to use if ~ else in JavaScript Code. I think I have to use if ~ else.

```
const toDoObj = {
   text: text,
   id: newId
 };
```

I think in above code I have to make limit on 'id'. But it is difficult to me.

```
function paintTodo(text) {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  const delBtn = document.createElement("button");
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  const newId = toDos.length + 1;
  delBtn.innerText = "Delete";
  delBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteToDo);
  span.innerText = text;
  li.appendChild(span);
  li.appendChild(delBtn);
  li.id = newId;
  toDoList.appendChild(li);
  const toDoObj = {
    text: text,
    id: newId
  };
  // Below code just meaning pop up window.
  // But, it didn't mean that I could save just 5 values in LOCAL STORAGE.
  if (toDos.length <= 5) {
    toDos.push(toDoObj);
    saveToDos();
  }
  else {
    alert("You just add 5 TO-DO lists.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to make limitation on LOCAL STORAGE values count like this image. If 'id' is 5. User can't add anymore in LOCAL STORAGE.

![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/42408554/67155288-03978500-f347-11e9-9f4f-5546efc68a22.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple before adding to todos you have to add check something like:

```
 if (toDos.length > 4) {
    alert("You just add 5 TO-DO lists.");
    return false;
 }
```

this will come at the starting of function paintTodo(text)

Comment: Thanks, It is working well !!
Code you mentioned has to be located on top of function.